# Why doesn't "base is derivedA || base is derivedB" work as expected?

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors

```
if (state is NoteInitial || state is NewNote)
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: state.notes.length,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return _NoteCard(state.notes[index], key: UniqueKey(),);
                  });
```

NoteInitial and NewNote are both derived from the abstract class NoteState, state is a NoteState. If I only write `if(state is NoteInitial)` then the code can compile, same if I write it with new NewNote, but if I write both, the compiler complains that `The getter 'notes' isn't defined for the type 'NoteState'.`  notes is defined in both of them, is this a problem with the compiler, or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler can only make sure that the property `notes` exists if it narrows down the type of variable to a specific type that has those properties.

I guess both of your types have this property but independently of each other? But the compiler cannot really know this. It has not narrowed it down to a specific type.

If so, then you may want to create another base class or interface, implement it for both of them and then make your `if` statement depend on that. Or maybe one of your states is a superset of the other, that would work too.

What I do is i have an abstract state called `NoteWithNotesState` that has a property `notes` and then both `NewNote` and `InitialNote` derive from that. Then you `if`could be `if(state is NoteWithNotesState)` and then you should be able to access the property with no problems.